# Persist Login across Domains

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cross-domain

I am running a simple ASP.NET MVC website in Visual Studio that can be accessed locally via multiple domains.

Here is the reproduction of my issue:

1) User views the site using domain 1.
2) User logs in successfully.
3) User views the site using domain 2.
4) Site acts as if the user had never logged in.
5) User view the site using domain 1.
6) The site now sees that the user is logged in again.l

So basically the user states are not being persisted across domains.  My initial thought is that the session states are not being shared across domains - is that what is causing this?  Is there an easy way to fix it?

### Update

This is currently how I have setup Authentication:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ConfigStartup))]
namespace Yeack
{
    public partial class ConfigStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder Application)
        {
            public void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder Application)
            {
                Application.CreatePerOwinContext<RepositoryManager>((x, y) => new RepositoryManager(new SiteDatabase(), x, y));

                Application.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
                    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, User, int>(
                            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                            regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateClaimsAsync(manager),
                            getUserIdCallback: (claim) => int.Parse(claim.GetUserId()))
                    }
                });

                Application.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my Web.config, I have the following property:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Based on these settings, is there a way to make multi-domain authentication work?

Comment: Authentication and session tokens are stored in cookies. Your browser doesn't send the cookies for domain 1 to domain 2 because it doesn't know that those are the same website. I'm not sure of a way around this, other than a single sign on. It's pretty easy to enable Microsoft or Facebook account integration in the default MVC templates.

Comment: If you "domain 1" and "domain 2" are like "www.sample.com" and "other.sample.com" consider if you can login on "sample.com" so cookies are set on root domain and visible to all sub-domains.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It is setup so that it can either be a subdomain or an entirely different domain.  But if I did login with a domain, would the subdomain automatically recognize it?

Comment: @JasonP - but how does a single sign on do it?  If the browser can't tell that two sites are related, why won't it try and make you go through the SSO authentication process for domain 2 even after you have done it for domain 1?

Comment: It will redirect you to the SSO service. But if you're authenticated with the SSO service, you'll be immediately redirected back to domain 2 and won't have to reenter your credentials.

Comment: but then how does the cookie know that you are authenticated?  I assume that with SSO you still use the Session states to access information about the currently logged-in user?

Comment: Hm, you'd be authenticated in both sites, but you wouldn't be able to automatically use built-in session functionality. You could probably roll your own in-memory or persistent session storage tied to the user id instead of a random session token.

Comment: @JasonP - how would this work?

Answer (score 1):

This is the method to get the token authorization from WebAPI.

```
RestUtils.GetTokenData(AppDefaults.UrlAPI, model.User, model.Pass);
```

This method persists on cookie that model.User is authorized using FormsAuthentication

```
Response.SetAuthCookie(model.User, true, model);
```

*Web.config*

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <!-- Authentication -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
    <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
</system.web>
```

*Extension.cs*

```
public static class HttpResponseBaseExtensions
{
    public static int SetAuthCookie<T>(this HttpResponseBase responseBase, string name, bool rememberMe, T userData)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(name, rememberMe);
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
        if (ticket != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration,
                ticket.IsPersistent, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData), ticket.CookiePath);
            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
            cookie.Value = encTicket;
            responseBase.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return encTicket != null ? encTicket.Length : 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }        
}
```

*LoginVM.cs*

```
public class LoginVM
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
}
```

*AccountController.cs*

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginVM model, string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["TokenData"] = RestUtils.GetTokenData(AppDefaults.UrlAPI, AppDefaults.ProxyConfig, model.User, model.Pass);
        Response.SetAuthCookie(model.User, true, model);
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    if (HttpContext.Session != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.Clear();
        HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
        HttpContext.Session.RemoveAll();
    }

    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: Do I have to specify Forms authentication in the Web.config?  I based my solution on the ASP.NET MVC Template which sets this setting to None and creates a custom OwinContext authentication - see my update above -